# How to prove $\log_23$ is irrational?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, irrational-numbers

I think using contradiction is good.

Assume $\log_23$ is rational

Then $\exists p\in \Bbb{Z}, q\in \Bbb{Z}^*: \log_23 = \frac{p}{q}$ ###$p, q$ has no common factors.

Then $3^{q}=2^{p}$

...

Here I failed to continue. Could someone give any advice?

Comment: $q\ne 0$, so $3$ divides the left-hand side. But not the right.

Comment: Prime factorization is unique

Comment: The right-hand side is even and the left-hand side is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\log_2 3 = \frac p q
$$
$$
2^{p/q} = 3
$$
$$
2^p = 3^q
$$
$$
\text{An even number} = \text{an odd number}.
$$

(Here we rely on the fact that this number is positive, so $p$ and $q$ are either both positive or both negative, and in the latter case, we just multiply them both by $-1$ and get positive numbers.  Thus $2^p$ and $3^q$ are integers.)